# Check in JavaScript/jQuery if the string contains all Chinese Characters or Ends with a Chinese Character

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the Title suggests, I need javascript/jQuery that helps me to check if the string contains all Chinese Characters or Ends with a Chinese Character.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i would try to do it like this:

1. get the char codes of chinese charachters (probably [here](http://www.khngai.com/chinese/charmap/tbluni.php?page=0))
2. go through the string with for-loop and get for each char the char code with `your_string.charCodeAt(i)`
3. proof if the char code in the char codes of chinese charachters